# What is the relationship between $\int_{a}^{\infty} x f(x) dx$ and $E(X)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

$X$ is a continuous random variable, and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx=E(X)$$

Then, what is the relationship between $\int_{a}^{\infty} x f(x) dx$ and $E(X)$?
I tried to use the integration by parts, but I have some difficulties.. Here's what I've done so far.

$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} x f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{a} x f(x) dx= E(X)-\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} {\int_{b}^{a} x f(x)} dx $$
$$ =E(X)- (a F(a)- \lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} {b F(b)}-\int_{-\infty}^{a} F(x) dx )$$

But I don't know how to calculate $\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} {b F(b)}$. I guess that $\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} {b F(b)}=0$, but don't know how to show it... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular relation, except the obvious

$$E(X)=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^{\infty}xf(x)dx.$$

Comment: But if one can say that $lim_{b \to -\infty} b F(b)=0$, then $\int_{a}^{\infty} x f(x) dx=E(X)-aF(a)+\int_{-\infty}^{a} F(x) dx$.. I'm wondering whether we can claim in this way.. Do you have any idea on  whether we can say $lim_{b \to -\infty} b F(b)=0$? @Yves Daoust

Comment: @sndwec: this leads yo nowhere.

Comment: @sndwec Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3161257/