# Finding expectation of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, integration, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with CDF $F$. Suppose that $P(X>0)=1$ and that $E(X) < \infty$. Show that $E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx$

I start out with the definition of expectation:
$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF(x)$$
Proceed with intergration by parts, letting $u =x$ and $v' = dF(X)$:
$$E(X)=xF(x)\rvert_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)dx$$
$$=xF(x)\rvert_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[1-P(X>x)]dx$$
let $t \rightarrow \infty$:
$$E(X)=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}tF(t)-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}-tF(-t)-[\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}t-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}-t]+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx$$
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}t-0-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}2t+\int_{-\infty}^{0}P(X>x)dx +\int_{0}^{\infty}1dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}P(X>x)dx$$
I am not sure where my faulty logic is here, but I presume I did something naughty with the limits (I am quite rusty on my calculus), or I am misunderstanding how to use the fact that $P(X>0)=1$. Why did I end up with $\int_{-\infty}^{0}P(X>x)dx$ and not $\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>x)dx$?

Comment: This question has appeared many many times. For a stronger result see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160795/proving-formula-for-math-expectation?rq=1

Comment: I was allowed to accept as fact that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} t(F(t)-1)=0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty} tF(t) = 0$